# How do I POST multipart form data with file upload and handle the response with Haskell?

Tags: haskell, post, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file to the CMU [Online Language Modelling tool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html) and I hope to retrieve the files given by links on the resulting page.

I followed the code in the `http-conduit` package documentation (latest is 1.9.4) but encountered an error. I've [logged an issue here](https://github.com/snoyberg/http-conduit/issues/134).

How would you do go about this in Haskell? I'm happy with using `http-conduit` but I think that bug could be a show-stopper.

Comment: It looks like you are missing some imports.  `fromJust` is from Data.Maybe and `Response` is probably from one of the Network.HTTP modules.

Comment: You're right about `fromJust` being from `Data.Maybe`. `Response` is a tricky beast. It's defined in `Network.HTTP.Conduit.Response` which isn't exposed by the package. Hence it's a bug: the example code uses it but it doesn't compile. I'm seeking for alternatives that work...